# max-width adjusts to fit text?

Tags: css

Not the best title, but anyway...

I have an element with a `max-width` and some text.

If the text is longer than will fit on one line, I get this:

```
----------------------------
|My text here, hello       |
|everyone!                 |
----------------------------
```

In other words, it takes up the full max-width, but there's an empty space on the right due to the word moving down.

Is there any way to make it so that this happens instead?

```
---------------------
|My text here, hello|
|everyone!          |
---------------------
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Width / Max-Width on Line Wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not Possible by CSS Alone

[According to BoltClock in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap), it is not possible. The explanation makes sense. For the line wrap to occur to begin with, the line needs to reach the `max-width` setting. Once done, it wraps, but it does not reshrink because it is using that size for the calculation of the wrap.

As far as I know, this is still not possible.

Comment: [float doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/ght3C/11/) either. Remember it needs to be a single line of text.

Comment: @Kolink--unless I am missing something, `float` (and all the others noted) work just fine in collapsing to the width of the text (whether one line or not). Is that not what you want? Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ght3C/14/) with a super wide `max-width`. It collapses the last four div's for me on IE8/9, Firefox 17, and Chrome 23... ahhh, but not if small enough if the line wraps [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ght3C/17/); that's what you are wanting, isn't it?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after ;) If a line is too long to fit.

Comment: @Kolink--at present there only appears to be a partial (not fully cross browser) to the issue. See my update.

Comment: @zooted: thanks. I deleted that portion because you were right, and to my knowledge, it is still not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve yet to find a method that does not require the use of both a wrapper element and JavaScript, but it’s possible that this one suits your needs.

```
<div id="example">
    <span id="content">My text here, hello everyone!</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

```
​var content = document.getElementById("content");

content.parentNode.style.width = content.offsetWidth + "px";​​​​
```

[a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgcv2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the above solution, but on the inner element set display: table-caption, and DON'T set max-width: 0px. This will include safari support (as well as Firefox 17 and IE8/9 and Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Feel like `word-break` is what you need http://caniuse.com/word-break although it is CSS3 new property with not such a wide support yet

Comment: I don't want the words to break though. Do you see any broken words in my examples?