# Element not shrinking to fit wrapping text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The block size must not be greater than necessary.

I need to avoid the space to the right of the red line...

[image]

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item-text {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-icon"></div>
  <div class="item-text">lorem a morem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this is still not possible, take a look here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672760/max-width-adjusts-to-fit-text)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is simply how CSS works when wrapping text.

You can avoid the problem by adding a `<br>` tag where you want the break to occur.

Something like this:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item-text {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-icon"></div>
  <div class="item-text">lorem a<br>morem</div>
</div>
```

Here's a more detailed explanation: **[Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276)**

Comment: the text is not controlled by me, and you need to work without <br>

Answer (score -1):

Use `word-break` property, like:

```
.item-text {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item-text {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-icon"></div>
  <div class="item-text">lorem a morem</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @HovsepMiskaryan Is this isn't what you need can you please post a image showing your problem?